# Assign multiple weights to a portfolio

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, risk-analysis

I have a dataset in excel that contains risk grade of customers. I have some survey data that projects proportion of customers with risk grade movements over a 3 month horizon. This is categorized into 3 groups. I am stuck at how to apply all 3 weight classifications such that the weights eventually assign to risk grade movement proportions.

Let me explain a bit:

[image: ![]

This is what my table looks like. The following is what my weights/proportions look like

[image]

Those numbers dont make sense but what I need to show is that approximately 8% of those 5 accounts have gone down a notch in risk grade (e.g. A1 moves to B2, or C3 moves to D4), 4% have gone down 2 notches (e.g. A1 has moved to C3) and 1% have moved 3 notches (e.g. A1 moved to D4).

Help please!

Comment: IIUC, it seems like there can be multiple solutions? Also, we don't know your grading schedule...

Comment: What do you mean by grading schedule?

Comment: The hierarchy of risk grades... `A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3` or whatever... just so we know what the result is given an existing risk grade and move of x notches. It's not really clear what the output should be.

Comment: Ok, can't share the exact schedule but lets say the grading is as follows: C87 D72 D67 D62 E57 E52 E49 E47 E45 E42 F35 F21 - (C87 is the best and F21 is the worst)

Comment: Given those inputs... what should the output be? Can you at least guesstimate it? It's just a bit unclear.

Comment: My apologies. The output should be revised risk grades based on those forecasts

Comment: Right so can you add a screnshot with them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213380/discussion-between-user2641784-and-bigben).